# How to check if response from server is a JSON object in Appcelerator?

Tags: json, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

How can I check in Appcelerator if response is a JSON?

I have tried the usual way in js.

```
Ti.API.info(response.constructor.name); // returns "String"
if (response instanceof JSONObject) //JSON object undefined
```

Other ways

```
        var response = this.responseText;

        if (response.constructor === {}.constructor){
            Ti.API.info('is object');
            response = JSON.parse(response);
        }
        else{
            Ti.API.info('not object');
            Ti.API.info(response.constructor); // returns some Krollback <KrollCallback: 0x7fbdc8c0abe0>
        }
```

I'm using substring, but that just seems flawed.

```
if (response.substring(0, 1) === "{")
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice of Prashant and Carlos, I used a try/catch inside the onload, thank you guys.

```
        var response = this.responseText;
        try {
            console.log("success");
            var response = JSON.parse(response);
            if (callback)
                callback(response);
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log("error parsing");
            if (callback)
                callback("error");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I am doing to verify a JSON response sent by an API:

```
// convert http response to json 
var CVT_ORDER_SEARCH_RESPONSE = JSON.parse(HttpResponse.responseText);

// verify json response parse returned valid object 
if (!CVT_ORDER_SEARCH_RESPONSE){
    throw 'Invalid JSON response returned by server.'; 
}
```

Also see : [JSON.parse Function (JavaScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc836466(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: I usually parse the response after I know it's a JSON, if I try to parse a non-JSON object, I get an error.

Comment: @Von, I usually handle such cases inside try-catch-finally block because I won't be sure that when server sends me improper JSON response, so it's better to handle them in try-catch instead of if-else because if-else needs actual values and/or data type.

Comment: Go for a Try Catch. That's the only way